# Material-UI Controllable table

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

Is there a tableRow property that can be used to make table a controllable component that can be used in redux? "selected" property doesn't let me change row's checkbox state as I like. For example in a controllable environment I'd like to be able to make a table that when a user clicks on first row, the second row gets selected and not the first row.

```
<TableRow selected = {this.state.isSelected}>
```

From what I experienced, this property only sets the default value and does nothing when this.state.isSelected's value is changed with setState() method.

Comment: Can you show the function that change this.state.isSelected state? or its 'default' behavior?

Comment: I recently faced the same issue, ended up disabling the material-ui table chceckboxes, and added them manually and i keep track of them using component state. You need to workaround a little to add custom onClick function to TableRow, but after that it's easy.

Comment: Yea, I did the same thing. It's a bit harder to maintain because you can't use some functions like onRowSelection() though.